# Button on click to scroll to specific word with highlight and on another click scroll to next occurence

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The objective is to click on a button that finds and scrolls to specific word highlighting it.
The next click on the same button would do the same but to the next occurence... so on ... so on

http://jsfiddle.net/KTwm3/6/

The above example is mostly what i need but i can't seem to adjust it and make it work with the mockup table structure

Table structure as an example (button to look for apples)

```
<div class="icePnlGrp" id="fgmevtcfm:j_id1386" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; overflow: auto;">
<table class="tblAlternate3">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:1" >ID</span></th>
<th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:2" >Quantity</span></th>
<th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:3" >Fruit Name</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="">1</td><td>example</td><td>apples</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">2</td><td>example</td><td>pear</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">3</td><td>example</td><td>banana</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">4</td><td>example</td><td>apples</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used Jquery. You can try it like this:

```js
const search = $('#search');
    const inputSearch = $('#input-search');
    const main = $('.tblAlternate3 tbody tr')
    let index = 0;
    let findText = 'appl';


    inputSearch.change(function () {
        index = 0
    })
    search.click(function () {
        findText = inputSearch.val().trim()

        let $occurrences = $('.tblAlternate3 tbody tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find(`td:contains("${findText}")`).length > 0;
        });
        if ($occurrences.length <= 0) {
            alert('Could not find');
            return;
        }

        if (index > $occurrences.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        clearSearch()

        let $next = $occurrences.eq(index++);
        const textReplace = $next.find('td:last-child').html().replace(findText, '<span class="hilite">' + findText + '</span>')
        $next.find('td:last-child').html(textReplace)


        $(document).scrollTop($next.offset().top - 35);
        return false;
    })

    function clearSearch() {
        let span = main.find('td:last-child')
        if (!span) return;
        $.each(span, function (index, value) {
            if ($(value).has('span').length > 0)
                $(value).has('span').html($(value).data('text'))
        })


    }

    // scroll our trigger link when the screen moves so we can click it again
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#trigger').offset({top: top, left: 0});
    });
```

```css
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html .hilite {
        background-color: #ff0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter search">
<button id="search">Search</button>
<hr>
<div class="icePnlGrp" id="fgmevtcfm:j_id1386" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; overflow: auto;">
    <table class="tblAlternate3" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:1">ID</span></th>
            <th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:2">Quantity</span></th>
            <th><span class="iceOutTxt" id="example:3">Fruit Name</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="">1</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="apples">apples</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">2</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="pear">pear</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">3</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="banana">banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">4</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="apples">apples</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">3</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="banana">banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">4</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="apples">apples</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">3</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="banana">banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">4</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="apples">apples</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">3</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="banana">banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">4</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td data-text="apples">apples</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```